# Range query with Edge

Tags: arangodb

Is it possible to do the range query against a Edge?

I'm doing "collection.range(attribute, left, right)", where collection is in fact a Edge.

And I got a "not implemented" error on ArangoDB 2.3.3(Win64).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible also for edge collections.
All that is required is a skiplist index on the attribute you want to run the range query on. Here's an example demoing it:

```
/* create some vertices */
var vertices = db._create("vertices");
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  vertices.save({ _key: "v" + i });
}

/* create some edges */
var edges = db._createEdgeCollection("edges");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  edges.save("vertices/" + i, "vertices/" + i, { value: i }); 
}

/* create the index */
edges.ensureSkiplist("value");

/* run the range query */
edges.range("value", 7, 23).toArray();
```

If no index is present, the in fact the "not implemented" may be thrown.

Comment: I have adjusted the error message in https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/b3fc335e3dc3dfc97b7df6e951482cc681625980 - "not implemented" was probably not very informative.